# how to implement NSData base64DataFromString equivalence in android

Tags: android, base64, decode, iso

everyone
I have an implementation for NSData base64DataFromString on IOS, which decode / convert the base 64 string to NSData
I want to implement the same in android.
What should I do in android?
Thanks in advance.

The following are IOS implement:

```
NSString *dataStr = [[[mDict valueForKey:@"good"] valueForKey:@"logo"] valueForKey:@"data"];
                //  NSLog(@"dataStr %@", dataStr);
                if( ! [dataStr isEqual:[NSNull null]] ){
                    NSData *thisImageData = [NSData base64DataFromString:dataStr];
                    [self.locationLogos setObject:thisImageData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", logo_num]];
                    //save
                    NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    [def setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.allLogos] forKey:@"allLogos"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the decode(String, Base64.DEFAULT) method from [android.util.Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#decode(java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: Thanks! I want to store the decoded data[]s in map, and show it in imageView without saving them in imagefile. How can I do this?

Comment: Depends what kind of data it is; better post a new question.